# Linux 'at' command history

Tags: linux, at

I got an email from root with the subject

> Output from your job #

I guess this came from my `at` queue because I recognized the command. But the thing is I submitted this `at` command 3 weeks ago and is also suppose to execute 3 weeks ago.

So I am now looking for `at` command history or log of some sort that will tell me the `at` commands that were issued in the last few weeks. Does anyone knows if such log exists?

Answer (score 1):

On my system I can find the list at `/var/log/cron/*`.
You might look for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, the cron history is stored in `/var/log/syslog`